# Black Line appears in Safari not Chrome using Ant Design Table

Tags: html, css, reactjs, safari

I'm using Ant Design UI Library in React.

Using Table Component and using fixed columns features like this,

The black line appears in Safari not Chrome.

I think it is a `box-shadow` issue. im not certain.

In my website, the table has this issue, but there is not that issue in [Ant Design Official Page](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-fixed-columns).

[bug in ant design table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9hbf.gif)